# Why do I get missing DLL errors debugging my Fortran code using GDB on Windows 7 64-bit (using Eclipse/Photran/Cygwin)?

Tags: windows, debugging, 64-bit, gdb, fortran

My setup is as follows:

- OS: Windows 7 Home Premium 64-bit
- Eclipse: Helios 3.6.1 64-bit with CDT
  and Photran
- Java SE Runtime
  Environment: 1.6.0_21
- Java Hotspot: 64-bit Server VM
  (build 17.0-b17, mixed mode)
- Cygwin 1.7.2 (32-bit)

My initial test Fortran application simply prints 'Hello World!' and exits.
The code builds and runs fine, albeit with the following 2 Warnings in the Problems tab in Eclipse

```
Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
Error launching external scanner info generator (gcc -E -P -v -dD C:/Users/Joe/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.cdt.make.core/specs.c)  HelloFortran    Unknown C/C++ Problem
Error launching external scanner info generator (gcc -E -P -v -dD C:/Users/Joe/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.cdt.make.core/specs.c)  HelloFortran    Unknown C/C++ Problem
```

The problem comes when trying to debug the app as a Local Fortran Application which results in this error:

```
cygwin warning:
  MS-DOS style path detected: C:\Users\Joe\workspace\HelloFortran
  Preferred POSIX equivalent is: /cygdrive/c/Users/Joe/workspace/HelloFortran
.gdbinit: No such file or directory.
  CYGWIN environment variable option "nodosfilewarning" turns off this warning.
  Consult the user's guide for more details about POSIX paths:
    http://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/using.html#using-pathnames
auto-solib-add on
Undefined command: "auto-solib-add".  Try "help".
Error: dll starting at 0x76ba0000 not found.
Error: dll starting at 0x75230000 not found.
Error: dll starting at 0x76ba0000 not found.
Error: dll starting at 0x76aa0000 not found.
[New thread 7060.0x10dc]
[New thread 7060.0x16c0]
```

I'm guessing the entry points aren't found because it's expecting 32-/64-bit DLL and getting the other type (correct me if I'm wrong). The GDB version is as follows:

```
GNU gdb 6.8.20080328 (cygwin-special)
GDB configured as "i686-pc-cygwin"
```

Running GDB from the command-line gives:

```
[New thread 5768.0x15a0]
Error: dll starting at 0x76ba0000 not found.
Error: dll starting at 0x75230000 not found.
Error: dll starting at 0x76ba0000 not found.
Error: dll starting at 0x76aa0000 not found.
[New thread 5768.0x46c]
hellofortran () at ../HelloFortran.f90:1
1    program HelloFortran
Current language: auto; currently fortran
```

If I'm reading that correctly the application does run in GDB and I am able to step through it, but what are the missing DLL errors about?

Dependency Walker gives the following errors for my HelloFortran.exe

```
Error: Modules with different CPU types were found.
Warning: At least one delay-load dependency module was not found.
Warning: At least one module has an unresolved import due to a missing export function in a delay-load dependent module.
```

The missing DLLs seem to be IESHIMS.DLL (2) which from my quick research doesn't seem to be a big issue but I don't see any reason my application would need to reference this DLL so I don't think this is leading to the errors in GDB.

All of the modules have a CPU type of x64 except for:

```
CYGGCC_S-1.DLL
CYGGFORTRAN-3.DLL
CYGWIN1.DLL
HELLOFORTRAN.EXE
```

which have a CPU type of x86

I'm concerned the missing DLL errors could harm my ability to debug my program properly (although the program will eventually run on a Unix-based HPC so I shouldn't run into these issues there since all those DLLs seem to be to do with Cygwin).

My questions:

- Why do I get missing DLL errors?  (Would switching to 32-bit versions of Eclipse/JVM etc fix this?)
- Am I
  okay to continue, or should I solve
  the missing DLL errors (and if so,
  how)?

Edit: My test program is as follows:

```
program HelloFortran
    ! Force variable declaration
    implicit none

    ! Print 'Hello World!' to the main output
    write (*,*) 'Hello World!'

    ! End program
end program HelloFortran
```

Comment: I've yet to see a single keyword from the Fortran language in this question. Could you post a minimum size example of fortran code which gives this kind of error, along with what you did to generate it, instead of guessing on the source of the problems?

Comment: Just edited my post - see the bottom of it for my test Fortran program.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why do I get missing DLL errors?

When Win/x64 sends a `DebugEvent` to 32-bit process about a 64-bit DLL that is part of that process, it necessarily truncates the load address (64-bit load address doesn't fit into 32-bit `LPVOID`). The end result is that the debugger sees a DLL load event, but can't find any DLL at that address; so warns you.

> (Would switching to 32-bit versions of Eclipse/JVM etc fix this?)

No: this is fundamental to debugging any 32-bit process on x64 (at least with 32-bit debugger). I *think* you would get rid of the warning if you use x64 version of GDB, but I am not sure if GDB/x64 can debug 32-bit processes on Windows (x86_64 GDB has no trouble with i386 processes on Linux due to "multi-arch" support; I don't know if "multi-arch" is present in Windows version).

> I'm concerned the missing DLL errors could harm my ability to debug my program properly

You shouldn't be.

> I don't see any reason my application would need to reference `IESHIMS.DLL`

What made you think it's `IESHIMS.DLL`?

More likely what you see is [WoW64.dll](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WOW64) and friends.
*Every* 32-bit application running on Win/x64 references `WoW64`.

Comment: Dependency Walker said it found 2 missing load-dependent DLLs in my .exe which it listed as IESHIMS.DLL (2) - so that was my thinking.

Comment: I tried with a 64-bit version of GDB from http://www.equation.com/servlet/equation.cmd?fa=gdb

Comment: The 64-bit version seems worse.

The GDB version is 7.2 and configured as "x86_64-w64-mingw32"

When running the program with the 64-bit GDB I get a lot of warnings:

warning: 'C:\Windows\system32\ntdll.dll': Shared library architecture 4 is not compatible with target architecture i386
(and 9 others very similar to that)
 Then the last warning is different - 
warning: cYgstd 28ccd5 d 3

The program works and exits normally as with the 32-bit GDB. Think I'll stick with the 32-bit GDB for the time being, thanks for all your help.